# Is a Mouse USB to PS/2 adapter identical internally with a a keyboard USB to PS/2 adapter?

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, adapter, ps2

I would like to buy a keyboard USB to PS/2 adapter. However on many websites I see Mouse USB to PS/2 listed separately than Keyboard USB to PS/2 adapters/ I wonder if they are internally identical or if they are different (i.e they map some USB pins to some different PS/2 pins)

Answer (score 2):

They are very different.

A USB to PS/2 converter is not a straight-forward wiring pin-out adapter between the 2 different connectors.
The converter contains a small chip that talks PS/2 (either the keyboard or the mouse version) to 1 connector and that acts as a USB device (which involves being able to correctly respond to various USB commands) to the other connector. This USB device must (among other things) identify itself to the computer as either a "USB HID mouse" of a "USB HID keyboard" as appropriate.

There are converters that have 2 PS/2 connectors so you can connect both a mouse and a keyboard to 1 USB port. Internally such converters identify themselves to the computer as USB device with 2 sub-devices (the USB standard allows for this).

Allegedly there also exist "smart" converters that can work with either a mouse or a keyboard and will auto-detect what is attached. I have never seen one myself so I can't tell you how well that works.

Comment: however I am talking about adapters not converters. I know that most keyboards and mouses that have USB plug actually can work internally as PS2 devices and can identify themselves as PS2 devices. What is needed is just a simple PS2 "adapter" not a converter.

Comment: @yoyo_fun There is no such thing. Electrically and protocol wise USB and PS/2 are NOT compatible at all.  You might be mistaken with keyboards that were originally designed for PS/2 and that later got a small USB-PS/2 converter chip added so they could be sold as USB keyboards. (There are quit a few IBM Model-M variants out there that were retro-fitted like this.) Still not a case of a simple adapter. The converter is still there.

Comment: There's a reason that the mouse adapter is typically colored green, with a mouse symbol on it, whereas the keyboard adapter will be purple with keyboard symbol.

Comment: @Tonny they exist. Many mouse chipsets have dual PS/2 and USB modes over the same cable. The mouse will power up, check what pins actually provided the power, and switch protocol modes accordingly. This is how passive adapters work. They are not real adaptors, since the actual power, data and pinout differences are done by the chip and not the plug. This is also neither universal nor standard.